# hashmap from text file isn't fully read

Tags: java, hashmap, text-files

so i've worked on hours end to come up with this code

```
public class instructorIO
{
    static Map<String, String> instructors;


    public static Map<String, String> getInstructors()
    {
        try
        {
          BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new FileReader("instructor.txt"));

             instructors = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

             String line;

            while(((line = in.readLine()) != null))
            {
                line = in.readLine();
                String[] val = line.split("<>");
                String ID = val[0];
                String name = val[1];

                instructors.put(ID, name);
            }
            in.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ioe)
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

        return instructors;
    }
}
```

when i try to display all the hashmap values in my text area, only hash IDs 2,6, and 4 are displayed. There are a total of 6... what am i doing wrong?

also when i try to do that with another text file, i get a Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at String[] val = line.split("<>");

Comment: "only hash IDs 2,6, and 4 are displayed" - this can be OK if your file only has 2, 4, and 6 keys. Keep in mind hashmaps can only have one value per key. Anyway, can you post your file contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading two lines at a time and only taking the second one:

```
        while(((line = in.readLine()) != null))
        {
            line = in.readLine();
            String[] val = line.split("<>");
            String ID = val[0];
            String name = val[1];

            instructors.put(ID, name);
        }
```

once in the `while` condition and again inside the loop body. I suggest you do it like this:

```
        while(((line = in.readLine()) != null))
        {                
            String[] val = line.split("<>");
            String ID = val[0];
            String name = val[1];

            instructors.put(ID, name);
        }
```

Comment: not yet. I'm getting an error with the 2nd part of the question.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at String[] val = line.split("<>");
the text file goes like:
1<>CIS 101-1
2<>CIS 101-2
3<>CIS 231-1
4<>CIS 231-2
5<>CIS 234-1
6<>CIS 234-2
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Comment: Are you sure you are getting `NullPointerException` in this new version? Because if `line` is null it will not enter the loop body, so it cannot reach the call to `line.split` with `line` null.

Comment: i tried fixing the code a bit into
    while(((line = in.readLine()) != null))
   {
    String[] val = line.split("<>");
    courses.put(val[0], val[1]);
   }
and when trying to use that txt file i gave in previous comment, i get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 now.

Comment: @cataschok: Well, I ran your code with the file you provided and I'm not getting any errors. Strange...

Answer (score 1):

You are calling:

line = in.readLine();

twice. Once in the while loop and once just after. So you are skipping every other line.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `line = in.readLine()` method twice in the `while` loop.